# Is it possible to install a USB device using a registry?

Tags: usb, windows-registry, serial-number

I am trying to create a white-list based on the serial number of usb devices that will be used to allow only certain usb devices to be installed. I wrote a script to get the serial number of a USB device but I can't find where to write it in the registry so that the computer understands it can be installed. Does someone know where the serial number of the installed usb devices are stored in the Windows registry ?

Answer (score 0):

Registry information for USB is described in the Microsoft article of
[USB Device Registry Entries](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/usbcon/usb-device-specific-registry-settings).

However, this does not help for restricting devices, only in getting information
about them.

Restricting USB access is done via Group Policy.

For more information see this (long) Microsoft article :
[Device Management and Installation Step-by-Step Guide: Controlling Device Driver Installation and Usage with Group Policy](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2008-R2-and-2008/cc731387%28v=ws.10%29).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The problem with the solution using the GPO is that the restriction is based on hardware ids and not on the serial number. Is it not possible to filter the usb devices according to their serial number?